# Why do we use the end Function?

Tags: php

Why do we use $extension = end($temp); in this code? What exactly does this do

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Comment: it returns the last item in the array

Comment: Why not simply use [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) with the PATHINFO_EXTENSION argument instead of that explode() and end()? (and watch out for case sensitivity in filenames)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`end()` **advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.**

**It does not JUST return the value.** It needs a `&reference` argument is it moves the internal array pointer too. There's no `next()` after `end()`. There's only `current()` or `reset()`.

Answer (score 2):

This example uses end() function to retrieve last element of $temp array. This last element contains extension of filename. http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Answer (score 1):

as Märis told you it gets the last element of the array, which in the case of your filename is the file extension (or will be the most time)

in the last line it is checked if the extension is one of the $allowedExts.

but it is redundant check, couse of the file type checks befor.